# Объединить метки про драйверы

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Нужно объединить метки [драйвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80), [драйверы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b), [драйвера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) и [drivers](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drivers).

Основной, я думаю, следует сделать [драйвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80).