# При объединении меток про драйверы, одну выпустили из виду

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

9 месяцев назад был вынесен вопрос [про объединение меток про драйверы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5232/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b).
Вроде все сделали, но вот сегодня всплыла метка [`драйверы`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797513/devcon-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-id-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).
За период около 3-х лет её использовали 5 раз (включая сегодня). Нужна ли эта метка вообще?

Предлагаю 2 варианта:

- удалить;
- объединить с другими схожими метками;

Comment: Объединить логичнее

Comment: @AK я тоже больше склоняюсь к этому варианту.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ Помогите разобраться с синонимами меток!

Comment: Уведомления так [не работают](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6939/176217).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удаление меток не работает так как этого ожидают предлагающие удаление. Рано или поздно метка создаётся снова.

Чтобы запретить создание тех или иных меток, нужно вносить их в специальный список явно запрещённых. Сделать это могут только сотрудники компании, обычным избранным модераторам это недоступно. А потому, надо просто досинонимизировать то, что недосинонимизировано по упомянутому вопросу. Это уже может сделать каждый рядовой модератор.

Comment: К кому обращаться, чтоб данный вопрос был решен? К модераторам с ромбом?

Comment: @VladSpirin да, к любому [ромбовидному](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).